# Access UIViewController from View

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, constraints, superview

I have this `UIView` which has its constraints, constraints is set to the parent view, which is `UIViewController`, every time I set the constraints, I have to pass the `currentViewController` so it can do this:

```
currentViewController.view.addConstraint(...)
```

I want the view to be able to set the constraint, in whichever view it is, I want to give my view responsibility to set the constraints to its parents without having to pass it as an argument, how do I do it? I've seen some answers in Objective-C but I want to do it in Swift, and I don't know how to.

I've tried using `view.superView` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should definitively use `view.superview` to setup constraints. But pay attention, you should add constraints only when your view is part of that hierarchy, which means, it should be already inside a view (`view.superview != nil`).

As a flow, you should first add your view as a subview to another view, than adjust the constraints based on the `view.superview`.

Comment: ill try doing this but i came up with this idea, when i initialize my view, i pass it its parent view and then i have parent as property, is it a good idea or not?

Comment: also, i want to set the constraints when initializing, so theres a problem, i have to initialize it, then subview it which is impossible i guess??

Comment: Why do you need the parent view as property, if you already have it as `view.superview`? Related to your idea, I don't think I've got it, but the main rule is that you can add constraints to a view, when it is a subview of another view.

Comment: i need parent view as property because when i create the view its parent view is nil, i want to add constraints when its initialized, since when its initialized it isn't automatically subview of the view i want it to be i need to store it as property

Comment: You should rethink you logic of doing that. It seems to be not the right one. Why do you insist to add the constraints on initialization? Those should be only added `when needed`. I would additionally suggest you inspect the `didMoveToSuperview` function of the UIView. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/didMoveToSuperview

Comment: i will consider that

Comment: i've figured it out thanks i didn't know about the didMoveToSuperview function